# solclient send request resulting success and fail at the same time

Tags: callback, request, timeout, solace

I'm starting a new project with Solace as the load balancer. As I follow the guideline on the [official doc](https://tutorials.solace.dev/javascript/request-reply/) to build a service that can send requests to Solace, I encounter a weird issue where my request is successful and fails simultaneously. Here's my code

```
function initSolace(pass: string) {
  var factoryProps = new solace.SolclientFactoryProperties();
  factoryProps.profile = solace.SolclientFactoryProfiles.version10;
  solace.SolclientFactory.init(factoryProps);

  session = solace.SolclientFactory.createSession({
    "url": "ws://localhost:8008",
    "userName": "tech_core",
    "vpnName": "testing",
    "password": pass
  }, new solace.MessageRxCBInfo(messageRxCb));

  session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.UP_NOTICE, function (sessionEvent: any) {
    requestData(10000).subscribe();
  });

  session.connect();
}

async function messageRxCb(session: any, message: any) {
  message = Parser.decodeBinaryAttachmentToPb(message, pnlPb.RespPnl);
  console.log('result from RxCb', message); // I got the correct response here
}

function requestData(timeout = 10000) {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    const parsedPayload = Parser.createPb({displayCurrency: 'USD'}, pnlPb.ReqPnl);
    const msg = Parser.encodePbToBinaryAttachment(parsedPayload, pnlPb.ReqPnl);
    const request = solace.SolclientFactory.createMessage();

    request.setDestination(solace.SolclientFactory.createTopicDestination('my/testing/topic'));
    request.setDeliveryMode(solace.MessageDeliveryModeType.DIRECT);
    request.setDeliverToOne(true);
    request.setBinaryAttachment(msg);
    session.sendRequest(request, timeout,
      (ses: any, message: any) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS', message);
        subscriber.next(message);
      },
      (ses: any, event: any) => {
        console.error('FAIL', event); // I got a timeout error here
        subscriber.error(event);
      },
      'correlation test'
    )
  });
}
```

As I run the code, I gets the timeout error from the **requestData** function AND the correct data from the **messageRxCb** function as well.
[image]

How does this happening? Did I miss any config here?

Answer (score 3):

The Request-Reply pattern is a closely coupled communication pattern.
Every request that is posted by the requestor requires a response from the replier within the timeout specified.

I see from your code sample that you have configured a timeout of 10000ms. What it means is that every request that is posted should receive an incoming reply within 10000ms. If this response is not received, then it would result in the timeout error that you see in the console.
The reason why you see that the request is successfull and the error is because while the request has been successfully posted, a reply was not received within the specified timeout.

Do you already have a replier setup for this interaction? If not then I would suggesting setting up a simple boilerplate replier listening on this and testing the flow again.

Additionally, it would be good coding practise to handle the timeout error in a functionally appropriate manner.

Regards
Hari

Comment: I agree with Hari's response ! You might even consider using another pattern if you dont really need to do a request-reply. Perhaps look into direct messaging?